# How to trigger the delete function in parent component from child component using @Output

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two components item-list and item. the list display a list of items that are provided through input. and each item has a delete button. So in this case, my item-list is the parent and item is child component. I tried to implement the delete function in the parent component by sending an output emitter event from the child component, but it logs error reading undefined property.

Below are the codes for the two components:

**item-list.component.html:**

```
<div>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill"
><input
  matInput
  placeholder="Add daily"
  (keyup.enter)="addTask()"
  autocomplete="off"
  [formControl]="nameControl"
 /></mat-form-field>
 </div>

<ng-container *ngIf="filteredData$ | async as data">
<div
cdkDropList
class="example-list"
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event, data)"
 >
 <app-item
  [value]="value"
  *ngFor="let value of data; index as index"
  (inputDataChange)="removeTask(index)"
  cdkDrag
 >
 </app-item>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

**item-list.component.ts**

```
public filteredData$: Observable<TaskType[]> | null = null;


removeTask(index: any) {
this.data.splice(index,1);
```

}

**item.component.html:**

```
<div class="listContainer">
<div class="checkcontainer">
<mat-checkbox [checked]="IsChecked"></mat-checkbox>
</div>

<div class="displayvalue" [ngClass]="{ 'line-through': value.task }">
 {{ value.task | uppercase }}
</div>

<div>
 <Matbutton mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
 </Matbutton>
 <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="removeTask($event)">
    <mat-icon class="deleteitem">delete</mat-icon>
    <span>remove</span>
  </button>
 </mat-menu>
</div>
</div>
```

**item.component.Ts:**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.scss'],
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
   [x: string]: any;

   @Input()
    value: any;

   IsChecked: boolean;

   @Output() inputDataChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   constructor() {
     this.IsChecked = false;
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {}

   removeTask(index: any) {
     this.inputDataChange.emit(true);
   }
  }
```

In the above code, the item-list component has a removeTask function, which results in error **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'splice')"**. Can someone help me with this error and show me where I went wrong ? . Thank you !

Comment: Why do you do `[x: string]: any;` in your component? That makes it so the compiler can't help you if you mistype properties. You are also not showing where `this.data` is defined and set in `item-list.component.ts` and the message is telling you that `this.data` is undefined. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your component has an observable called `filteredData` which is using the async pipe to create a template variable, you cannot use that from your component.Try `inputDataChange)="removeTask(data, index)"` and use the data that is passed in.

Comment: Could you provide code on stackblitz?

Comment: I think the title of your question is not accurate.  You don't need help with triggering the delete function.  It looks like you want help emitting a new value through your observable when.  Is that what you want?  As Vasile Coman points out below, you don't have a property called `this.data`, so you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `data` in your item `item-list.component.ts` only in html. In your `item-list.component.ts` you have access to filteredData$. It is a BehaviorSubject or an Observable?

If it is a BehaviorSubject you can do the following:

```
removeTask(index: any) {
   const data = this.filteredData$.value
   data.splice(index,1)
   this.filteredData$.next(data);
}
```

Comment: the filteredData$ is an observable